# Защита от SQL инъекции в PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Всем добрый вечер! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу защитить свои MySQL запросы от SQL инъекции?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '$search'";
$query = "SELECT username, subject, message, DATE_FORMAT(created, '%d-%m-%Y %T') AS `date` FROM messages WHERE id='$a'";
```

И так далее...

Написал вот такую чудо функцию на PHP:

```
function sanitizeString($var)
{
    trim($var);
    strip_tags($var);
    htmlspecialchars($var);
    stripslashes($var);
    mysql_real_escape_string($var);
}
```

Только эта функция почему-то вычищает все под чистую ;-((

Подскажите, пожалуйста, мне верное решение данной проблемы. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Тааа лааадно вам, ребяяят =) Как будто в ответе моем все было неправильно =) Ну ошибся в 2-3 строчках и что?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username
   LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string ($search)."'";
Тему можно закрывать!

Comment: Чето не пойму, как ваша функция работает если результат она не возвращает и `$var` передается не по ссылке?

Comment: @Asen минусы дают шанс подумать! иногда подумать после того как сделать тоже хорошо!

Comment: да ладно, и без них можно думать,поверьте! =))))

Comment: *[Не удержался](http://kstatida.ru/a/1089/vozderzhites-ot-ispolzovaniya-smajlov)*

Comment: оффтоп: @AlexWindHope цитата из ссылки - "Особые чувства я питаю к смайлу ХД и его вариациям. Если ещё и раскладку переключить лень…" (очень хорошо подметил человек)

Comment: Биндинг ИМХО проще и надёжнее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В функции нет return $var; в конце, поэтому и ничего не возвращает. И вы не правильно применяете функции, нужно

```
$var = mysql_real_escape_string($var);
```

иначе в return вернется то что вы и передавали изначально.

И зачем там все это ? Достаточно одного mysql_real_escape_string, только если magic_quotes_gpc включен, входящие данные нужно еще обработать функцией stripslashes(). И не забывайте данные в запросе обрамлять кавычками, иначе никакой mysql_real_escape_string вам не поможет.

Comment: Ок, спасибо, сейчас исправлю... Хотел написать уникальную функцию, чтобы использовать ее для очистки пользовательского ввода(в формах), но видимо не судьба.

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно `mysql_real_escape_string()`